# Zend 2 Multiple access

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I build a shop with Zend Framework 2 where you can by digital stuff like music and download them.

Now i have a the following situation:
I have a controller that controlls all downloads. I start to download a large file and it takes several minutes until the download is finished. While i am downloading, i can't browse in my shop with the same browser that I use for the download.

Is it possible to configure zend 2, so that i still can browse my website while downloading or is this impossible due to the fact that i execute the same script by launching the application througb the index.php file?

### Update

```
 $response = new Stream();
    $response->setStream(fopen($finalFilePath, 'r'));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setStreamName(basename($finalFilePath));
    $headers = new Headers();
    $headerArr = array(
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($finalFilePath) .'"',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'Binary',
        'Content-Length' => filesize($finalFilePath),
    );

    $headers->addHeaders($headerArr);

    $response->setHeaders($headers);
    return $response;
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894005/running-concurrent-php-scripts)

Comment: You also post the code of your controller as that seems relevant to the question.

Comment: @hotzst  i added the code of the controller / method that is called if i download a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It has something to do with sessions !

just call
    session_write_close();

before the "return".